# open modal in foundation using reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using foundation for css. When an icon is clicked to add persona, a modal should appear. How can i open a modal without using jquery?

Here is my code

```
export default class Campaign extends Component {
  state = {
    adsShow: false,
    personasShow: false
  };

handlePersonasClick = () =>
  this.setState({ personasShow: !this.state.personasShow });

renderCampaigns = () => {
  return campaigns.map((campaign, i) => {
    return (
      <Collapsible
        key={campaign.name}
        trigger={this.campaignTitle(campaign)}
        classParentString="campaignsCollapse">
        <div className="Ads">
          <span className="cmpTitle">Ads</span>
          <span className="editCampaign">
            <FaPlusCircle onClick={this.handleClick} />
          </span>
        </div>
        <div className="AdsList">
          {this.state.adsShow
            ? <CreateNewAd
                personasClick={this.handlePersonasClick}
                personasShow={this.state.personasShow}
              />
            : null}
          {this.renderAdLists(campaign.ads)}
        </div>
      </Collapsible>
    );
  });
};
render() {
  return (
    <div style={{ padding: '10px 20px' }}>
      <h3>Campaigns</h3>
      <div className="campaignsContainer">
        {this.renderCampaigns()}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
}


const CreateNewAd = props => {
  return (
    <Collapsible trigger={adsTitle()} classParentString="adsCollapse" open>
      <p>
        Personas
        {' '}
        <span><FaPlusCircle onClick={props.personasClick} /></span>
        {props.personasShow ? <Personas /> : null}
      </p>
    </Collapsible>
  );
};

export const Personas = () => {
  return (
    <div
      id="myModal"
      className="reveal-modal"
      data-reveal
      aria-labelledby="modalTitle"
      aria-hidden="true"
      ref={modal => {
        this.modal = modal;
      }}
      role="dialog">
      <h2 id="modalTitle">Awesome. I have it.</h2>
      <a className="close-reveal-modal" aria-label="Close">×</a>
    </div>
  );
};
```

the following code snippet  is on the CreateNewAd component which is a child component of Campaign Component. When FaPlusCircle icon is clicked a modal should appear. How can i do that when following top to bottom approach and without using jquery ?

**UPDATE**

have created a sandbox. here is the link https://codesandbox.io/s/qx9Pv1lry . You have to click on magazine print. An accordion menu shows up. After that click on click text that is aside Ads text. There you will see open modal text. Where clicking should open a modal which is what the question is about.

Comment: Which `<FaPlusCircle />`? Looks like the one within `CreateNewAd` is going to set state that should at least render the `Personas` component. Whether it's visible depends on the CSS of the modal itself.

Comment: Do you mean to say, CreateNewAd should be stateful component?

Comment: No, but I see two `<FaPlusCircle />` components. One within `CreateNewAd` and one within `Campaign`. The one within `Campaign` is currently wired up to a non-existent method. It'd be super helpful if you could drop what you're working with into a jsfiddle.

Comment: Judging by the JS shown, I'm pretty sure the `Personas` component will be rendered. As for if the proper CSS is going to show it, that's a different matter

Comment: I have created a sandbox. here is the link https://codesandbox.io/s/qx9Pv1lry. You have to click on magazine print. An accordion menu shows up. After that click on click text that is aside Ads text. There you will see open modal text. Where clicking should open a modal which is what the question is about. Thanks.